# Is there an established monastic order, with the beleifs and practices same as the Goenka school of meditation?

Tags: vipassana, monasticism, sangha, sn-goenka

Let me clarify,what I want to know is

(a) 'An established monastic order' - This the Goenka school is not.

(b) With principles and beleifs and aims as close to the Goenka school as possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> (a) 'An established monastic order' - This the Goenka school is not.

There is no Goenka School. Generally this is referred as the linage of [Saya Gyi U Ba Khin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ba_Khin) and [Ledi Sayadaw U Ñanadhaja](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ledi_Sayadaw). Also it is influenced by [Webu Sayadaw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webu_Sayadaw)

[Ledi Sayadaw U Ñanadhaja](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ledi_Sayadaw) and [Webu Sayadaw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webu_Sayadaw) are Buddhist monks. Also there many teachers who are Buddhist Monks who are particle according to [S. N. Goenka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S._N._Goenka).

> (b) With principles and beliefs and aims as close to the Goenka school as possible?

Many of the references in the [disclosure](http://www.vridhamma.org/The-Discourse-Summaries) are meticulously referenced from the [Tipitaka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tripi%E1%B9%ADaka). So any monastic order which practices which is close to the Tipitaka would share the same beliefs.

Comment: Thanks. Of course they would share the same beleifs, but do they actually carry out such practices ?

Comment: Goenka teachers what U Ba Khin taught which is a based on Ven. Ledi Sayadaw linage and Ven. Webu Sayadaw.